# Phonegap localStorage returns the string "[object Object]" instead of the object

Tags: javascript, html, object, cordova, local-storage

I trief to use the localStorage object in Phonegap, but instead of getting an object, the getItem only receives a string `"[object Object]"`:

```
var storage = window.localStorage;
storage.setItem('test',{'name':'mark','greeting':'Hello'});
console.log(storage.getItem('test'));
```

In the console of Google chrome it says:

```
[object Object]
```

The output of "console.log(storage)" is the following:

```
Storage
...
test: "[object Object]"
```

If I try to access a property of the object it just says "undefined":

```
storage.getItem('test').name
```

Any ideas how to get this to work?

Comment: Are you sure the console isn't just **displaying** [object Object]? What does `console.log(storage.getItem('test').name)` show?

Comment: Just found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage

Comment: When you try to store anything other than strings, setItem will call ".toString()" on it, which in your case is "[object Object]". Do what Martinj says below, stringify it first. Furthermore, this has nothing to do with PhoneGap, but is a UIWebview/Webkit issue.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

HTML5 `localStorage`allows you to store [strings only](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html#methods).

You'll have to perform a `JSON.stringify` when you store your object, and `JSON.parse` when you retrieve it.

Comment: Im using dojo and did dojo.toJson and dojo.fromJson

Comment: The stringify and parse approach is worth gold. But on Android (testing in in-app browser on 2.3.3 on Samsung), the following error occurs: "Web Console(5504): Uncaught illegal access at file:///android_asset/www/"etc if I try this: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('purchases'))

Comment: @Wytze: does the error also occur if you just do `localStorage.getItem('purchases')`, without the JSON.parse? Because "illegal access" sounds like the problem lies with localStorage, not with JSON.

Comment: Thanks Martijn. Turns out the error occurred if the item was still empty. LocalStorage.getItem('purchase') would return null, and that would cause JSON.parse to throw the illegal access error.